# Command line to initialize SonarQube database?

Tags: database, installation, sonarqube

I'm trying to automate sonarqube installation.
One (small) issue I'm running into is after installation during first access, as sonarqube is initializing the db schema, we run into timeouts.
I'd like to know if there's a script/command to initialize the db (create tables and all) from the bash?
I've been digging on the internet and couldn't find an answer to that.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to complete answers from Seb and Jeroen.
Schema is indeed created programmatically by SonarQube during startup. This step can't be executed independently in a script. Just start server. Instead of parsing logs, I suggest to call the web service GET http:///api/system/status (see documentation at http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/system/status) to know when database is fully initialized.

Database upgrade when installing a new release can also be triggered through the web service POST http:///api/system/migrate_db (see http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/system/migrate_db).

Comment: Calling the status WebService is indeed a cleaner solution. But careful, though, to not start polling to fast after SQ startup or be ready to handle a few "connection refused" errors. Tomcat has to start up and be able to handle the request otherwise the connection won't succeed. In addition, Tomcat might hold the first request until SQ itself has started enough and is able to reply. If so, the first request will take longer to be replied to.

Comment: So the solution would be to start the service, wait like 30 secs and then do a long http GET call on status to initialize the db?

Answer (score 2):

Database initialization is built-in SonarQube and can not be run independently of starting SonarQube.

As suggested by @jeroen, you can indeed analyze the `sonar.log` file and wait for the `web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started` line.

Answer (score 0):

You can build in a wait loop and/or analyze the SonarQube log file during startup.